# How do I search for names with H in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

It should be simple but it is not working

```
 SELECT * FROM profile WHERE name LIKE = 'H%';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= 'H%'' at line 1
```

Columns from table

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM profile;
+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type                                                        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(10) unsigned                                            | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(20)                                                 | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| birth | date                                                        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| color | enum('blue','red','green','brown','black','white')          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| foods | set('lutefisk','burrito','curry','eggroll','fadge','pizza') | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| cats  | int(11)                                                     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
```

What should I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove = in your select statement
so;

```
 SELECT * FROM profile WHERE name LIKE  'H%';
```

Answer (score 1):

After removing the `=` as **Areca** recommends. It sould work fine *(without errors)* 
 **But** you can use different options for different outcomes.

1. To find all names that contains a letter **H**, you should use 2 `%` one on both sides. 
    Like this: `SELECT * FROM profile WHERE name LIKE  '%H%';`
2. To find all names that starts with the letter **H**, you should use 1 `%`. 
   Like this: `SELECT * FROM profile WHERE name LIKE  '%H%';`